# When typeOrm uses JavaScript mode, table annotations do not take effect

Tags: typeorm

The following code shows that the automatically created table does not have table annotations. I am using the latest version of MySQL, and typeorm is also the latest version. Please help, why? Typeorm already supports table annotations in the previous version.

```
const {EntitySchema} = require("typeorm");
const main = require("../main");

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
    name: "SelectGroup",
    target: main.model.Jiaoyiri,
    columns: {
        id: {primary: true, generated: true, type: "int"},
        ym: {type: "varchar", length: 32},
        data: {type: "text"}
    }, uniques: [{
        name: "idx_ym", columns: ['ym']
    }],
    comment: "date",
})
```

I want this issue to be addressed so that table annotations can be automatically generated into the database.